# Java - byte[] to String to byte[] conversion error

Tags: java, string, byte

When trying to construct a String from a array of type byte[] and then converting back to byte[] array using String.getBytes(), some byte values are modified. Below is a piece of code that reproduces my issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[] { (byte)0xff, 0x5e};
    String str = new String(arr);
    byte[] arr2 = str.getBytes();
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        System.out.print(String.format("%02X ", arr2[i]));
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        System.out.print(String.format("%02X ", arr[i]));
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
3F 5E FF 5E
```

I have tried conversion with all of standard charsets and yet the result is the same. For a reason I'm not able to figure out, 0xFF becomes 0x3F...
Why, and how do I correct this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. This code depends on the default charset encoding of the JVM.

Comment: Which is why we don't use the default encoding, but specify it when using `getBytes()` and `new String()`. A 1-byte encoding such as `ISO-8859-1` should work just fine.

Comment: With a platform default of UTF-8, you see the problem, but using e.g. `new String(arr, "ISO-8859-1");` the conversion works okay.

Comment: passing "ISO-8859-1" to getBytes has solved the problem. Thanks Mick!

Answer (score 1):

After some helpful answers, here is how I got it to work:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[] { (byte)0xff, 0x5e};
    String str = new String(arr, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
    byte[] arr2 = str.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        System.out.print(String.format("%02X ", arr2[i]));
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        System.out.print(String.format("%02X ", arr[i]));
}
```

The charset used above has allowed me to use bytes of any value without having them converted, which is useful for working with binary data.

Comment: If you're working with binary data, you don't convert bytes to characters. Characters are for **text** data.